# Setting nested optional parameters in Vue 2 router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm creating a search engine with multiple filters users can pick, along with a query. All of those are optional and add up to the filtered result set.

So all these cases are possible and being properly stored in an object of keywords:

- Searching with a query
- Searching by country (without specifying any query)
- Searching by type (without specifying any query)
- Searching a query with a country and a type
- ...

What would be the best way of handling this with Vue Router? I want the search route to be updated with whatever filters are picked.

As far as I can tell I can't use multiple optional parameters and unless I specify all possible combinations (which is a bit silly) like:

```
export const routes = [
{ path: '/search', name: 'search', component: Search, children: [
    { path: 'query/:query, component: Search },
    { path: 'type/:type', component: Search },
    { path: 'country/:country', component: Search },
    ...
]},
```

... I don't see any other way of solving the problem. What would be the best option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option can be to use query params, so your URL will look like this:

> /search?country=sire&type=middleearth

You can access these from [$route.query](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/route-object.html).